# using setSfGuardUser() to save the current user in the model

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

My application makes use of the sfGuardUser plugin.  One of my tables has a relation onto the sf_guard_user table so there is a corresponding setSfGuardUser() function in the base model.  From Actions.class.php, I am attempting to set the current user into the object using this function, (Which I then save in the database).
my attempt:

```
->setSfGuardUser($this->getUser());  //called from inside Actions.class.php
```

this throws an error:

```
Couldn't call Doctrine_Core::set(), second argument should be an instance of Doctrine_Record or Doctrine_Null when setting one-to-one references.

...# at Doctrine_Record->coreSetRelated('sfGuardUser', object('myUser'))
```

Which makes me think that getUser() is not returning a sfGuardUser object, though I don't know how to check this.  Can anyone offer any insight?

Comment: By the way, what I'm currently doing is:

    ->setSfGuardUser(Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUser')->findOneByUsername($this->getUser()->getUsername()));

which seems a little unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->getUser()` returns a `myUser` instance. You need `$this->getUser()->getGuardUser()`.